# Convert one-dimensional associative array to two-dimension

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with key-value pairs like

```
array('123' => 'element1' , '256' => 'element2' , '789' => 'element3')
```

I want to convert this array in such a way that I will get

```
array(array('123' , '256' , '789'))
```

I tried with `array_keys`, but it's returning me

```
array(
[0] => '123',
[1] => '256',
[2] => '789',
)
```

What can I do to get the desired output?

Comment: In your title you want to convert a 2 dimensional array into a 1 dimensional array. But in your question you want the reverse?!

Comment: PHP shows you the index number of each item in your 1-dimensional array. You can access its elements using `myArray[0]`, `myArray[1]`, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you would want to do this, but you want to do something like this:

```
$newArray = array(array_keys($oldArray));
```

Comment: @DevCDR Well that's a contradiction with your question title. So unclear what you wanted here!

Comment: Now with editing the question title you let me look like a fool!